# Parsing a string to specific unknown word for referencing

Tags: java, parsing, split, substring

I have a map that I am referencing within my JFrame in a JList/ScrollPane object so it displays like this:

```
tongs ... 4.99

oven mitt ... 9.99
```

and so on. I want to use the users selection to populate a textbox in another form. I have this working just fine, however it currently displays the whole string with the ... [price]. I'd like to only display the object.

I've thought about using the .split method, but I'm not sure if that's correct. Any ideas to help me out here?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource().equals(view.getSubmit())) { 
        dialog.setObject(view.getSelection()); // This prints the whole string as shown above
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
    ...
}
```

`setObject()` goes to a method tied to a textbox. Instead of displaying 'oven mitt ... 9.99' I'd like it to only say 'oven mitt'. The hard part is that the number of words vary, so I cannot just say take substring xyz.

---

EDIT: I got it using the following code.

```
            if(e.getSource().equals(view.getSubmit())) { // Launch kiosk

            String search, val = null;

            search = view.getSelection();

            for (myEnum d : myEnum.values()) {
                if (search.contains(d.getLocation())) {
                    val = d.getLocation();
                }
            }

            dialog.setDestination(val);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Comment: Can you include the code that is doing the changing?  Without that, I can't really tell what you mean by it including the whole string.

Comment: If you are using a JList then you would need to provide an array or some other object that holds your data, one that can be referenced to only retrieve what you specifiy. If you designed your program with MVC in mind then it shouldn't be that difficult. As it is now, we do not know what `view` is or even the actual output that needs to be parsed.

Comment: It is a JList, however it is built with an EnumMap.